# Usage of "as" as a conjunction

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, as

Clearly here is a usage of "as" that i can't understand; as far as i understand, "as" is a subordinate conjunction that joins main clause + sub. clause.
Here we have ",as" joining two complete sentences.

Despite the relative quiet, the mood in Kyiv had been darkening for weeks, as senior military officials acknowledged that Ukraine’s long-awaited counteroffensive had largely stalled and international attention shifted to the war in the Gaza Strip.

Comment: Much trad grammar treats the "as" in your example as a conjunction. But modern grammar classifies it as a preposition with a clausal complement.

Comment: You can understand the "as" here roughly as "given that [senior military officials acknowledged...]".